# mean of a percentage of 2 rows in spss

Tags: spss

I have data of the following kind

```
pers.id       holiday
1                  0
1                  1
1                  0
1                  0
1                  1
1                  0
2                  0
2                  0
2                  1
2                  0
5                  0
5                  1
5                  0
9                  0
9                  0
9                  0
9                  0
```

I now want to compute the mean of the percentage of holidays/workdays.
In this case we have 4 persons. The number of rows for each person.id is the number of
days he has been working. So if pers.id has 6 rows he has been working 6 days. Holiday can either be 0 or 1 whether that person had a holiday on that day or not.
I now want to compute the mean of holidays/workdays for all person.id

In the above example that would be:

```
( 2/6 + 1/4 + 1/5 + 0/4) / 4
```

How can I do this in SPSS Syntax ? I also need a Confidence Interval for that value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is an example of using `AGGREGATE` to generate the requested table of proportions. There are so many different confidence intervals for proportions (see this [NABBLE discussion](http://spssx-discussion.1045642.n5.nabble.com/Confidence-interval-of-proportion-td1090471.html) that also links to various code snippets) so I'll let you figure out which confidence interval you want on your own.

```
data list free / pers.id holiday.
begin data
1                  0
1                  1
1                  0
1                  0
1                  1
1                  0
2                  0
2                  0
2                  1
2                  0
5                  0
5                  1
5                  0
9                  0
9                  0
9                  0
9                  0
end data.

DATASET DECLARE AggProp.
AGGREGATE
  /OUTFILE = 'AggProp'
  /BREAK = pers.id
  /HolidayT=SUM(holiday)
  /HolidayP=MEAN(holiday)
  /NId=N.
```

Comment: thanks a lot. I'm using EXAMINE ... /CINTERVAL 95  for the Confidence Interval.

Comment: The `CINTERVAL` subcommand may be good enough for govt. work, but if the proportions are near 0 or 1 and/or the number of observations are small I wouldn't statistically advise that. From the aggregate table I supplied it is pretty easy to calculate the Agresti-Coull correction (add 2 successes and 2 failures and then use the normal approximation).